# How to get external style sheet data for element that has been changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, external

I've got an element whose position has been changed via javascript on my page and I need to retrieve the original (external) style for it.  What's the best way to accomplish this?  I'm assuming there has to be something better than deleting the element and creating a new one so it has default values.  JQuery solutions are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: You changed position of an element and want the original position?

Comment: Yes, that's all I need.  And yes, it is necessary to change it and then get the original again, there's really no other way to accomplish what I'm after.

Comment: Why not keep the original value in a javascript variable and then place it again using jquery.css method?

Comment: I was sort of trying to avoid variable clutter, so I was hoping there would be something more dynamic to directly access the external stylesheet.

Comment: How are you changing it the first time? With jquery.css?
That function injects style attribute to the element, you can just remove that attribute and the changes will be gone.

Comment: Well, I suppose knowing how the method I'm using actually works is probably useful.  Thanks for the help, friend.

Comment: So you're using jquery.css to modify? Let me know to write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery.Css method injects "style" attribute to the modified element and that overrides all previous css from external file. 
To recover default css you can just remove the "style" attribute.

```
$(selector).removeAttr("style");
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the original as a data attribute for the element:

```
$('#element').data('original-css',$('#element').css('top')).css('top','20px');
```

then to restore:

```
$('#element').css('top', $('#element').data('original-css'));
```

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming the element is repositioned by modifying its style directly (e.g. using jQuery's `.css()` method), you can do this:

```
// De-jQuerify the element.  We need to get the style directly
var element = element.length ? element[0] : element;

// Store the currently-defined positioning that may be overriding
// the stylesheet.
var cur = {top: element.style.top, left: element.style.left};

// Remove any overriding positioning
element.style.left = element.style.top = null;

// Find the position of the element.
var pos = $(element).offset(); // Or $(element).position()

// Restore the old styles
$(element).css(cur);
```

This also ought to work correctly for elements that don't have their position overridden.